# Keep python operations in binary

Tags: python, numpy, binary

Using numpy and just trying to print martices in binary  :

```
import numpy

G=numpy.matrix('100011;010101;001110')

H = numpy.matrix('011100;101010;110001')

print G
print H
```

returns

```
[[100011]
 [  4161]
 [   584]]
[[  4672]
 [101010]
 [110001]]
```

How can I keep my matrices in binary and also to do matrix operations in binary as well? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

By "binary" do you mean "boolean"?  (And why in the world are you using the syntax that you're using??)

```
import numpy as np

g = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 
              [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
              [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=bool)

h = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
              [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
              [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=bool)
```

As far as the difference, consider `1 + 1`.  In binary, you'd get `2` (`0b10`). In a boolean representation, you'd get `1`.

So, if you want `[0, 1] + [0, 1]` to be `[1, 0]`, then you want binary.  If you want it to be `[0, 1]`, then you want it to be boolean.

Similarly, if you want `[1, 1] + [1, 0]` to be `[1, 0, 1]`, then you want it to be binary. If you want it to be `[1, 1]`, then you want it to be boolean.

As an example of a few of the operations you mention (using booleans):

```
print 'g * h ...'
print g * h

print 'g * h viewed as integers...'
print (g * h).view(np.int8) # or x.astype(int), but the latter makes a copy

a = np.array([1, 1, 0], dtype=bool)
print 'Matrix multiplication of [1, 1, 0] with g...'
print a.dot(g) # Or we could do g.T.dot(a)
```

This yields:

```
g * h ...
[[False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False]]

g * h viewed as integers...
[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]

Matrix multiplication of [1, 1, 0] with g...
[ True  True False  True  True  True]
```

Comment: I mean binary, I'm trying to implement syndrome decoding off of the G generator matrix and H as the parity check matrix. I'm use to working with MATLAB for handling this work of thing, so I defaulted to that syntax for matrices since it was possible. Thank you for your input but I don't know if I can get the correct result from operations if I implement the values as Boolean.

Comment: I'm confused... If you want things as "binary", then prefix it `0b`. E.g. `0b11` yields `3`.  Your arrays will (correctly) be integers, in that case. (You could print them in their binary representation by doing `print bin(x)`)  If you want arrays of the individual bits, then you want a boolean representation... What do you want `G * H` or `G + H` to return?

Comment: Ideally I could have a var of say [1,1,0], multiply this by G and have it return [1,1,0,1,0,1]. G*H should return a matrix of all zeros.

Comment: Then you don't mean binary, you mean boolean. You can view it as 0's and 1's if you like by doing `g.view(np.int8)`.  (On a side note, I used `array`'s in my answer, but you could just as easily use a `matrix`, as well. However, if you want `G * H` to be a 3x6 array of zeros, then you want an array, not a matrix.)

Comment: Alright, sorry for being obtuse here, you're being very helpful, but I'm looking for binary addition as in 1+1 = 0, and 1*1 = 1. Boolean does not handle operations this way, and this is why boolean is not what I'm looking for. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: And how did you do that?